# Eigen multi-thread operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, linear-algebra, eigen

Eigen is a C++ template library for linear algebra ([site](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)). According to the documentation, newer Eigen versions support the usage of OpenMP to take advantage of multi-threading characteristics. Their official documentation mentions that *some* operations can be ran in paralell ([documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html)).

However, which -concrete- operations are susceptible of these advantages is not mentioned in any place. The only place I have been able to find something states that matrix and vector multiplication can be ran in parallel, but no more information is provided ([here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.0)).

I would appreciate if someone could share a bit of knowledge about this uncertainty.

Comment: You should probably try asking on their forums...

Comment: That could be a good idea. I have taken the habit of asking the questions here in SO after having made the correspondent search in the web without results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Eigen's source directory:

```
$ find Eigen -type f | xargs grep -i openmp
```

...shows that only the general matrix by matrix product (GEMM) is using OpenMP (for now!).